# Spring MVC class cannot be converted to object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring project. Here is the code.

```
public ModelAndView SController(ModelMap model)
{
    P p = new P();
    List<Object[]> myList = (List<Object[]>)this.myservice.getList("abcd");

    for (Object[] lst : myList)
        p.setName(lst[0].toString());

}

public List<Object[]> getList(String name)
{
     return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM P WHERE c_name LIKE ")
        .setString(0,  "%" + name + "%").list();
}
```

I am getting the error on this line

```
for (Object[] lst : myList)
```

Error

```
request processing failed nested exception is java.lang.classcastexception: com.site.MyClass cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Why this error is coming?

EDIT:

SnapShot of debugger
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Could you double-check what the `list()` method returns ?

Comment: I checked in eclipse debugger. It returns an array of data!

Comment: debugger snapshot please update if possible.. Thank you

Comment: provide complete code.  "QUERY" means what ? is it hibernate query or simple sql query ? model return by getList must not be Object[]...  It must be MyClass as your exception says that..

Comment: @VikrantKashyap, added the screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying answer after query is provided in your question as below :

```
public ModelAndView SController(ModelMap model)
{
    P p = new P();
    List<P> myList = (List<P>) this.myservice.getList("abcd");

    for (P lst : myList)
        p.setName(lst.getName());

}
```

Here we can typecast the list to have more generic type of list. It might give warning which can be suppressed as we know it will always return list of P objects.

```
public List getList(String name)
{
     return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM P WHERE c_name LIKE ")
        .setString(0,  "%" + name + "%").list();
}
```

this getList method will return list of P objects where c_name like your name input

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSONObject instead. It is suitable for array of data.

Answer (score 1):

This is the javadoc of `list` method:

```
Return the query results as a List. If the query contains
multiple results per row, the results are returned in an instance
of Object[].
```

`list` returns only `List`, which is not type safe, it can be `List<Object[]>` or just `List<Object>`. You need to check if the list contains single object or object array:

```
List list = this.myservice.getList("abcd");
   for (Object o : list) {
       if(o instanceof Object[]){
          Object[] array = (Object[]) o;
       } else {  
          //object
       }
   }
```

**EDIT**

Class cast exception says it cannot convert `MyClass` to `Object[]`, my guess is hibernate deserializes directly into `MyClass` instance. Re-implement your code according to this. You can check it by investigating `List list = this.myservice.getList("abcd");` I gave above in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

try this may help you out..[Click](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/)